# I am getting error in Woocommerce plugin. SoapClient class is not enabled on your server; Some gateway plugins that use SOAP may not work as expected

Tags: wordpress

When I enter Wordpress woocommerce status, there is an error with red text: SoapClient class is not enabled on your server; Some gateway plugins that use SOAP may not work as expected. How can I fix this error? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php-soap library on your webserver.
There are a number of guides on how to install this library which depend on what operating system you have installed on your webserver.

Comment: How do I install the php-soap library? Would you tell? My operating system is windows.